# Using PgRouting Topology?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, topology

I have a data set of roads which is line and its projection system is `WGS UTM (EPSG:32639)` I have added it into my database and created a topology using this query

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('ways', 0.00001, 'geom_2d', 'gid',rows_where := 'gid>0', clean := TRUE);
```

The above query works fine. But When I try to route using any alogorithm such as this query

```
    SELECT id1 as path,b.geom as the_geom
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid as id, source, target, st_length(geom_2d) as cost FROM ways',
                           483,507,FALSE ,FALSE) a,
ways b
WHERE a.id1=b.gid
```

It returns some lines which are not a route at all. Here is an example

[image]

In above image the yellow lines is my edges, points are vertexes which are created by `pgr_createTopology` and blue lines is the result of routing 
I have tested different values of `tolerance` such as `1`,`10`,`100`,`0.00001`,`0.001` and for some of them there is no result and for some f them the result is exactly the same, I think there is something wrong with layers topology but I can not figure out how to fix it.

Can you help me to fix my problem?

edit 1:
here is the result of this query

```
SELECT * FROM "ways" WHERE gid=483 or gid=507
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the result of:  SELECT * FROM ways WHERE gid=483 or gid=507;  and provide the result of: SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE gid=483 or gid=507;

Comment: @kttii thanks my friend. I have ran "SELECT * FROM "ways" WHERE gid=483 or gid=507" and it returns two rows.I am attaching my results to my question

Comment: @kttii You know my queries for routing return some results but It seems that resulting lines are not complate. In the first image you can see some results that are shown ..

Comment: looks like some columns got cut off.

Comment: yes, I ran into the exact same problem and thought that my topology didn't get built correctly but it really had to do with picking the correct IDs.  Are there columns called SourceID and DestID in the ways table?

Comment: @kttii yes..My table has around 60 columns. which columns do you want me to share?

Comment: @kttii yes all columns such as source,target, cost are presented, How did you manged to build topology correctly?

Comment: ok, lets start over...  what is the "way.gid" of the start road and "way.gid" of the end road that you want to calculate with pgr_dijkstra()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pgr_dijkstra():

1. locate the ways.gid of the start road

   > assume the ways.gid = 483
2. locate the ways.gid of the end road

   > assume the ways.gid = 507
3. locate the vertex of the start road that you want to start at (can be source or target)

   > assume the ways.target = 1234
4. locate the vertex of the end road that you want to end at (can be source or target)

   > assume the ways.target = 5678
5. your simple statement will look like this:

   > SELECT *
   >      FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid, source, target, cost FROM ways',
   >                                 1234,5678,FALSE ,FALSE);
6. if you have a large dataset like mine (all of north america), then you'll want to filter with a bounding box using the ids of the road

   > SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost 
   >           FROM ways, (SELECT ST_Expand(ST_Extent(geom),0.01) as geombox  FROM ways as filteredways WHERE filteredways.id=483 or filteredways.id=488) as box 
   >           WHERE ways.geom_way && box.geombox'
   >   ,1234,5678,FALSE);
7. If you want to get back the total distance, then you can join back on the ways table

   > SELECT SUM(km) FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost 
   >           FROM ways, (SELECT ST_Expand(ST_Extent(geom),0.01) as geombox  FROM ways as filteredways WHERE filteredways.id=483 or filteredways.id=488) as box 
   >           WHERE ways.geom_way && box.geombox'
   >   ,1234,5678,FALSE) as r
   >   LEFT JOIN public.na_2po_4pgr as w ON
   >       r.edge = w.id;

Answer (score 2):

First hint:

I don´t think that your cost should be the length of the edges. It is a value that means minutes needed to travel that edge. With the length as value it means you need 100minutes for a 100m way. Thats no problem for Dikstra when units don´t matter but should be considered when you want to evaluate it.

Second:

You are joining the outcome of the pgr_dijkstra with your original ways. The function is meant to join with your nodes layer. That way you add the geometry of your ways with the id that is actually meant for the nodes of your route. Thats why you get random lines as these are the lines with the id of your route-nodes. Just alter the join from "ways" to the layer of your nodes. The outcome is a pointlayer which sequence you can use to plot your route.

Comment: Dear Matte, I will consider your note about costs, But about my problem you said I have missed start and end point. But this is start and end point (483,507) in second query,Can you please explain a little more?Also I think that the step of calculation of nodes from each segment is done by pgr_createtopology function,isnt it?

Comment: You are correct, i just miss interpreted your select statement and mixed up some comema. Edited the answer as i just run your statement with my network and found the mistake.

Comment: thanks for your help,I think there is something wrong with ,my topology,by the way I can easily route with ARCGIS,But I have this problem with pgrouting, Do you know how can I check for topology of network?Or find the best value for tolerance ?

Comment: Well ArcGIS has lots of "convenience functions" where it assumes a lot and calculates stuff in the background(don´t know what it does at the network manager though). Or puts the needed entries in a well sorted dialog. You need in general more time for many open source tools to get around with and they don´t want to  calculate stuff without the user explicitly calling it(and understanding it in the first place).

Comment: Yes I agree, anyway I don't know where is problem with my network. Finding the problem is half of solving it :((

Comment: @MajidHojati To state what Matte said another way...  pgr_dijkstra() is a bit confusing at first.  You passed in the Source ID as 483 and Target ID as 507.  Do IDs 483 and 507 correspond to your Edges or your Vertexes?  As Matte said, you need to provide the IDs of your Vertexes.

Comment: @kttii Thanks for your help but I am adding vertex id's..I thing there is sth wrong with topology and things like that,But I dont know how to fix it